# Remove white-space after "/" in a string with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Very new to RegEx

I need to remove whitespace after `/` character in a string if it exists

Ex

find/ replace other stuff >> find/replace other stuff

I am trying `.replace(/[/]+$/g, "")` but it has no effect

I am using this in a Google Apps Script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex remove white space after text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573706/regex-remove-white-space-after-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match a forward slash (`\/`, escaped since `/` is used as a regex delimiter char) and then any 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) to replace with a backslash:

```
s = s.replace(/\/\s+/g, '')
```

Or, capture the forward slash with a capturing group (a pair of unescaped parentheses, `(...)`), and replace with a replacement backreference `$1`:

```
s = s.replace(/(\/)\s+/g, '$1')
```

See the JS demo:

```js
console.log("/abc/   spaces/   more spaces".replace(/\/\s+/g, '/'))
console.log("/abc/   spaces/   more spaces".replace(/(\/)\s+/g, '$1'))
```

All occurrences are replaced because `g` (global) modifier is used.